# Build task groups: Choose which build variables are listed under parameters

Tags: azure-devops

We are using a task group for all of our builds. Some of the steps pick variables from variable groups and some variables are just system varibles like $(Get-Date).

When editing the task group all variables detected in the build steps are listed under the parameter section and concequently all builds will also show this list of varibles for the corresponding task group.

However in our case we would only like to display three of the variables. We would like variables such as $(Get-Date), some configuration variables and variables from the library variable group not to be listed since the user should not be able to edit these parameters.

Is there a way to choose which parameters will be listed under the task group or in the corresponding builds?

[image]

Comment: Don't really understand the parameter section part  in your task group. Could you specify more, a screenshot of your task group or a simple example?

Comment: I don't think is available, Azure DevOps display all the variables that exist in the task group.

Comment: Hi @LeviLu-MSFT please see the attached screenshot of the task group parameter section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there is no way to control which parameter should be listed under task groups.

But there is way to control who have the permission to edit these parameters.
If it is acceptable to you, You can modify the security of the task group, which allows you to control the edit permission for individual user and also groups.

[image]

After you deny a user's permission to edit the task group. User will get an error when he tries to change the parameter.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The user should be able to edit some of the variables. But he shouldn't be able to edit the steps in the task group.